# Windows Server: how to create a new user specifying home directory?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server

I need to add an RDP user to my win server 2008.

I'm able to create but in this case i have a specific need. this user MUST NOT HAVE a home folder with . appended.

if I create a new 'pippo' user, it will be created with their home as pippo.domain, but this make a 3rd party legacy sw to crash !

So I want to create the new user giving to it the home folder 'pippo', and NOT pippo.domain.

How can I do this?

**NB: we are not using Active Directory**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways of creating home folder not just for domain users...

To assign a home folder to a domain user:

> 1. Click Start, point to Programs, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Active Directory Users and Computers.
> 2. In the console tree, click Users.
> 3. In the Details pane, right-click the user account, and then click Properties.
> 4. In the Properties dialog box, click Profile.
> 5. Under the Home folder, type the folder information. 
>      To do this, follow these steps:
>      To assign a home folder on a network server, click Connect, and then specify a drive letter.
>      In the To box, type a path. This path can be any one of the following types:
>      Network path, for example:
>      \server\users\tester
>      You can substitute username for the last subfolder in the path, for example:
>      \server\users\username
>      Note In these examples, server is the name of the file server housing the home folders, and users is the shared folder.
> 6. Click OK.

You have [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816313/how-to-assign-a-home-folder-to-a-user) the steps to create home directories for users

Comment: We're not using active directory